# Calculate flux graphically

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $F = <x, y>$ and $C$ be the vertical line from $(1, 1)$ to $(1, 0)$ directed downwards. Find the flux of $F$ across $C$.

The correct solution would be 
$$
\int_{C} \overrightarrow{F} \cdot \widehat{n} \ ds = \int_{C} <x,y>\cdot <dy,-dx> =\int_{y=1}^{0} xdy =\int_{y=1}^{0} 1 \ dy = -1
$$

However, graphically, it seems like $\widehat{n}$ points to the left along the line. So, 
$$
\widehat{n} = <-1, 0>
$$
$$
\int_{C} \overrightarrow{F} \cdot \widehat{n} \ ds = \int_{C} <x,y>\cdot <-1, 0> \ ds =\int_{C} -xds =\int_{y=1}^{0} -1 \ dy = 1
$$

This produces the wrong answer. Why is that so?

Answer (score 0):

Someone (thanks a lot!) told me what was wrong. I'm not sure if he wants to remain anonymous. So, I'll just post the answer he provided.

"The problem with your solution is that ds measures distance travelled 
along the curve, in the direction of motion, so it is NOT true that
ds = dy.  The integral with respect to ds can be evaluated geometrically:

integral of -x ds = integral of -1 ds = - integral of ds = - length of 
the curve = -1.

Or, if you absolutely insist on converting the integral with respect to 
ds into one with respect to dy: ds = -dy in this case (because distance 
travelled = negative of the change in y), and then you'd be ok with your 
method after taking into account the sign change, but you don't actually 
need to set up the integral with respect to y."